# Postfix/SSL/Dovecote - can't send email

Tags: thunderbird, email, postfix, smtp

I know this looks similar to other questions on this forum, but they don't seem to be the same core problem as the one I'm experiencing.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I have postfix, dovecote installed on the machine.  I'm using dovecote to supply the SASL service to postfix for sending email.

If I connect to my server by hand,

```
openssl s_client -connect my.server.com:465 -starttls smtp
```

I can authenticate properly, using plain authentication

```
ELHO localhost
AUTH PLAIN base64==
```

If I try to send email from Thunderbird (running on my mac), the client hangs.
If I add tracing to postfix for my domain, the traces don't make sense.  It looks like Thunderbird is sending garbage instead of valid SMTP commands, and then not processing the error codes that are coming back from postfix.  The trace below has been sanitized, but only to the extent that IPs and other identifying marks have been anonymized.  In particular, the lines that start with "<", which are the SMTP commands coming from the server, have not been modified.

```
name_mask: plaintext
xsasl_dovecot_server_connect: auth reply: SPID?1916
xsasl_dovecot_server_connect: auth reply: CUID?2
xsasl_dovecot_server_connect: auth reply: COOKIE?251582cd3a4c5c6bf55cb3dcd7b4ca93
xsasl_dovecot_server_connect: auth reply: DONE
xsasl_dovecot_server_mech_filter: keep mechanism: PLAIN
xsasl_dovecot_server_mech_filter: keep mechanism: LOGIN
watchdog_pat: 0x7fee42fb0640
< <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]: ???
match_string: ??? ~? CONNECT
match_string: ??? ~? GET
match_string: ??? ~? POST
match_list_match: ???: no match
> <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
watchdog_pat: 0x7fee42fb0640
< <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]: ??????????????
match_string: ? ~? CONNECT
match_string: ? ~? GET
match_string: ? ~? POST
match_list_match: ?: no match
> <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
watchdog_pat: 0x7fee42fb0640
< <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]:
> <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]: 500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax
watchdog_pat: 0x7fee42fb0640
<host> dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user>, method=PLAIN, rip=<my.ip>, lip=<server.ip>, mpid=1922, TLS, session=<aeBDooH3KACi+7mG>
<host> dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user>, method=PLAIN, rip=<my.ip>, lip=<server.ip>, mpid=1924, TLS, session=<D/hNooH3KQCi+7mG>
smtp_get: EOF
match_hostname: <my-ip>.myisp.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
match_hostaddr: <my.ip> ~? 127.0.0.0/8
match_hostname: <my-ip>.myisp.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
match_hostaddr: <my.ip> ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
match_hostname: <my-ip>.myisp.com ~? [::1]/128
match_hostaddr: <my.ip> ~? [::1]/128
match_list_match: <my-ip>.myisp.com: no match
match_list_match: <my.ip>: no match
send attr request = disconnect
send attr ident = smtps:<my.ip>
private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
input attribute name: status
input attribute value: 0
private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
input attribute name: (end)
lost connection after UNKNOWN from <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]
disconnect from <my-ip>.myisp.com[<my.ip>]
```

Since it works by hand, it feels to me like I have the postfix/dovecote/SSL issues sorted, but maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Ugh, perfect. Just as I posted this, I thought of something else to try, and it worked. I withdraw the question.

For any folks who are interested, I'm using the wrong port. The 465 port is the default for SSL/TLS, but I had it set up to use the STARTTLS protocol.

What a doofus.